# Internet speed very slow on Fedora 34 running on a VM with Host on Windows

Tags: linux, fedora

I recently installed Fedora 34 on a Oracle VirtualBox VM with my host running on Windows 10. I noticed that even to open a single website it takes a long time or when I use sudo dnf update or when I try to install a software. I am connecting the VM to the internet via Local LAN (Bridged Adapter).

When I try to test the Internet Speed using `www.speedtest.net`, it gets stuck on Finding Optimal Server.

On Windows, the internet speed works well and as expected.

Output of `ifconfig`

```
        [rajiviyer@fedora ~]$ ifconfig

        enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500

        inet 192.168.1.7  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255

        inet6 fe80::2ecf:6dbe:e340:a3f6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>

        ether 08:00:27:dc:f4:0c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

        RX packets 4883  bytes 5631694 (5.3 MiB)

        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0

        TX packets 4223  bytes 446036 (435.5 KiB)

        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Please advice on how to resolve to match the download speed with my Windows host machine?

Thanks!

Comment: A few suggestions: Check if DNS might be the culprit by using IP addresses instead of domain names. Check ping return trip times. Check if the problem occurs when accessing the host or other devices on the local network from the guest. Use file transfers (curl, wget etc) for testing. Use tcpdump on the guest and Wireshark on the host to find suspicious traffic.

Answer (score 1):

disable ipv6 in network manager and see if it helps.

Comment: Blocking IPV6 is easy, so worth a try. But is it a DNS problem?

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank your for your contribution. Please note that your post looks like a comment rather than an answer. You may want to edit it to explain why you came to the conclusion that IPv6 vs. IPv4 may be a problem here.